# Clustering markers, if is it in a cluster

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have a google maps' code for clustering markers, where i want to check if marker is in cluster.
I use library MarkerClustererPlus v3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var markers = [];
        var mlen = 5;
        for(i = 0; i < mlen; i++) {
            var r1 = (Math.random()*180-90);
            var r2 = (Math.random()*180-90);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(r1,r2),
                title:"Marker: " + (i+1)
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        {
            zoom : 1,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            scaleControl : true,
            mapTypeControl : true,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        for(i = 0; i < mlen; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
        markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            zoomOnClick : false,
            maxZoom : 22,
            gridSize : 130
        });
        for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    //how to check if marker is in a cluster or not????
            alert(markers[i].isInCluster);//true or false
                    //or how to define a isInCluster(marker)
        }
    }
```

And html-code

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
```

Have enybody some ideas? That it would work also markers outside of screen.

Thanks for hints: beginner

Comment: You can get an array of markers which are in the cluster using `markerClusterer.getMarkers()` method. What exactly are you trying to do?